# OpenProcess() Access_Denied with SeDebugPrivilege

Tags: c++, winapi

This program enumerate all handles and get their names.

For pID 4 OpenProcess gets error 5 with SeDebugPrivilege.

UAC off. Running from Admin.

**Enable SeDebugPrivilege**

```
BOOL EnableDebugPrivilege(BOOL bEnable)
{
HANDLE hToken = nullptr;
LUID luid;

if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken)) return FALSE;
if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid)) return FALSE;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokenPriv;
tokenPriv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tokenPriv.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tokenPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes = bEnable ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tokenPriv, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL)) return FALSE;
_tprintf(_T("Privileges error: %d\n", GetLastError()));
return TRUE;
}
```

**Enumerate handles**

```
DWORD EnumerateFileHandles(ULONG pid)
{
    HINSTANCE hNtDll = LoadLibrary(_T("ntdll.dll"));
    assert(hNtDll != NULL);
    PFN_NTQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION NtQuerySystemInformation =
        (PFN_NTQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION)GetProcAddress(hNtDll,
            "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    assert(NtQuerySystemInformation != NULL);
    PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE NtQueryInformationFile =
        (PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE)GetProcAddress(hNtDll,
            "NtQueryInformationFile");
    DWORD nSize = 4096, nReturn;
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION pSysHandleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)
        HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, nSize);
    while (NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, pSysHandleInfo,
        nSize, &nReturn) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pSysHandleInfo);
        nSize += 4096;
        pSysHandleInfo = (SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION*)HeapAlloc(
            GetProcessHeap(), 0, nSize);
    }
    DWORD dwFiles = 0;
    _tprintf(_T("Handles Number: %d\n"), pSysHandleInfo->NumberOfHandles);
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < pSysHandleInfo->NumberOfHandles; i++)
    {
        PSYSTEM_HANDLE pHandle = &(pSysHandleInfo->Handles[i]);
        if (pHandle->ProcessId == 4)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(
                PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, pHandle->ProcessId);
            if (hProcess == NULL)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("OpenProcess failed w/err 0x%08lx\n"), GetLastError());
                continue;
            }
            HANDLE hCopy;
            if (!DuplicateHandle(hProcess, (HANDLE)pHandle->Handle,
                GetCurrentProcess(), &hCopy, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, FALSE, 0))
                continue;
            TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
            if (GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hCopy, buf, sizeof(buf), VOLUME_NAME_DOS))
                wprintf(L"p%d:h%d:t%d:\t%s\n", pHandle->ProcessId, pHandle->Handle, pHandle->ObjectTypeNumber, buf);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            CloseHandle(hCopy);
        }
    }
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pSysHandleInfo);
    return dwFiles;
}
```

On windows 7 x64 it's work fine. 
But on Windows 10 x64 OpenProcess returns error 5 with SeDebugPrivilege.

How open system process(pID 4) on windows 10.

Comment: The system prevents certain types of access to protected processes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights

Comment: I know it. This applies not only to Win10 but also to Win7 and Win8.


[This application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18975/Listing-Used-Files#_comments) gets a handle of the system process (PID 4) in the same way as my application and it works on Win10. How do i do it in my application?

Comment: That Codeproject app has a driver. What happens if you run it without the driver forcing it down its other codepath?

Comment: you try open [protected process](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=116). usually you can got only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | SYNCHRONIZE` access

Comment: as separate note - code very not efficient, contain errors and leaks

Comment: If i run that Codeproject without a driver  everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a handle for it as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) for OpenProcess specifically says it'll fail:

> If the specified process is the Idle process or one of the CSRSS
>   processes, this function fails and the last error code is
>   ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED because their access restrictions prevent
>   user-level code from opening them.

If you want to get system process names, you could try to use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` to get the snapshot of the process, then use `Process32First()` and `Process32Next()` to enumerate the all process.
Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string> 
#include <TlHelp32.h> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);
    HANDLE hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);//get the snapshot 
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        cout << "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Error!" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    BOOL bResult = Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32);
    int num(0);
    while(bResult)
    {
        cout << "[" << ++num << "] : " << "Process Name:"<< pe32.szExeFile << "  " << "ProcessID:" << pe32.th32ProcessID << endl;
        bResult = Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32);

    }
    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
}
```

Hope it could help you!

Comment: I need to get the names of open process files like in [this application](https://ibb.co/bP8vvwN)